# How to count alphabetic characters in a string?

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to do this:

```
$string = "this is a test sentence";
```

What I wanted to do was search for alphabetic characters in that sting and show how many of each character is in there something like this:

'T' is used 3 times in the sentence.

'i' is used 2 times in the sentence.

I tried `ctype_alpha()` and some other things but I can't get quite the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Or `count_chars`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code please.

> `array_count_values()` is PHP function which returns the count of each
>   character in an array. So we need to split up the string into an array, using `str_split()`, and then use `array_count_values()` to count it.

```
$string = "this is a test sentence";
$k = array_count_values(str_split($string));
print_r($k);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9c1a0cb2938135aacb4b5ad622515cecb37b4e0)

Comment: Let me be the one who announces that this answer _IS_ incorrect.  It is including spaces in the result and that is not asked for.  Maybe you'd like to `str_replace()` before splitting.

Comment: On top of that, the OP asked for Alphabetic characters, this answer returns numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to look specifically for alphabetic characters, it's probably best to use a regular expression rather than just `str_split`, which will give you all the characters, alphabetic or not.

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]/', $string, $letters);
```

The regular expression matches individual characters, so each full pattern match in `$letters[0]` will be one alphabetic character.

Once you have an array of letters, you can use `array_count_values` to count them.

```
$letter_counts = array_count_values($letters[0]);
```

If you want to sort the result alphabetically, `ksort($letter_counts)` will do it.

---

If you *do* use `str_split` instead, you can filter out the non-alpha characters from the result.

```
$letters = array_filter(str_split($string), 'ctype_alpha');
```

Comment: I might recommend `preg_split()` because it won't create unnecessary array depth. https://3v4l.org/nV1ZF

Answer (score 0):

The following code will take each letter of the string, set it as the key in an array and count up for each letter. If you don't want case sensitivity, run the string through `strtolower()` or similar first.

```
<?php
$string = "this is a test sentence";

$counts = [];

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($string);$i++){
    $char = $string[$i];
    if(!isset($counts[$char])){
        $counts[$char] = 0;
    }
    $counts[$char]++;
}

var_dump($counts);
```

To sort based on keys do this:

```
ksort($counts);
var_dump($counts);
```